# Factor Analysis using IBM SPSS for Likert Scale

Tags: spss, factor-analysis, cronbachs-alpha

I'm running a factor analysis of a Likert questionnaire that have a Cronbach's Alpha of 0,9.

I'm trying to figure out if my process for factor analysis of the strength of the correlation between two bodies of information inside the questionnaiere is correct and if it could be improved.

So,

In IBM SPSS I included all the information and then:

1. Created a correlation matrix and removed all correlations with Pearson correlations < 0,5.
2. Then I made a new analysis of those constructs and found a KMO >0,7 of the new group I want to research.
3. Then, using the variations of two constructs I want to analyse I made a Pearson correlation, Varimax rotation, two tailed for factor analysis.
4. With the Pearson correlation of the variations of the constructs I want to analyse I found the strengh of my relationship.

I'm missing something in my analysis?

I tried to keep it short.

Thanks.

Comment: Varimax is an oblique rotation. If you do varimax the correlation will be zero, because you defined it as zero.

Comment: Your process of factor analysis is a bit confusing. Why not just click the factor analyze menu?

Comment: About question 1)I'm not just using "click the factor analyze" because Kaiser himself, in 1974 says that only data with KMO above 0,6 should be considered for factor analysis.

Comment: About question 2) I'm using varimax because for my particular case I want to maximize the sum of variations. As it's written in this book: Statistics in a Nutshell, 2nd Edition. by Sarah Boslaugh

Comment: Sum of variations of what? Varimax is an orthogonal rotation, so your factors will correlate  zero.

Comment: Kaiser wrote that 50 years ago. The problem then was that a computer was the size of your house and had about 1% of the power of your cellphone and I don't think SPSS even existed. So you didn't do factor analysis unless you were sure it was going to be worthwhile, so you'd check the KMO. You don't care any more, you just do factor analysis.